# Display a WooCommerce custom checkout field value on email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

I'm having some problems with passing my custom field variables to the email receipt. I've browsed through StackOverflow but unfortunately none of the answers/solutions helped in my case.

The fields I have created do actually show up properly in the admin dashboard and in the after checkout page, it just won't show the variables in any email.

Here's where I am creating my custom field in functions.php:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Bezorg moment') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'options'     => array(
        '17:30-18:00' => __('17:30 - 18:00', 'woocommerce' ),
        '18:00-18:30' => __('18:00 - 18:30', 'woocommerce' )),
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Bezorgtijd'),
    'placeholder'   => __('Zo snel mogelijk'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_date' ));

echo '</div>';  }

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
```

Here's where I update the post meta:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( ! empty( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Bezorg moment', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) );
} }

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
```

Here's where I pass the value to the admin order dashboard:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Bezorg moment').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Bezorg moment', true ) . '</p>'; }

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
```

And here's where I am attempting to pass these values to new-order notification:

```
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Bezorg moment').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Bezorg moment', true ) . '</p>'; }

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
```

However, no matter what I try, the label will show up in the email but the variables always pass an empty value. I can't really figure it out because the exact same echo does properly display the values on the front end and in the dashboard backend. What am I doing wrong or what is different about the email part?

Many thanks in advance.

WordPress: 5.1
WooCommerce: 3.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - There are some small mistakes like:

- Since Woocommerce 3, to get the order ID from the Order object use: `$order->get_id()`
- On your last function, there is a missing parameter variable from the hooked function, So you can't get the correct WC_Order Object `$order` variable required in your code.
- The correct post meta key is

Optional advices:

- It's better to use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` action hook introduce in Woocommerce 3, instead of old `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` action hook.
- You can use `WC_Data` `get_meta()` method with the `WC_Order` object instead of `get_post_meta()`

Here is your complete revisited code:

```
// Display a custom checkout select field after Order notes
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h2>' . __('Bezorg moment') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'options'     => array(
            '17:30-18:00' => __('17:30 - 18:00', 'woocommerce' ),
            '18:00-18:30' => __('18:00 - 18:30', 'woocommerce' )),
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Bezorgtijd'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Zo snel mogelijk'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_date' ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save the dropdown custom field selected value as order custom meta data:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_date']) && ! empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'Bezorg moment', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) );
    } 
}

// Display the custom field value on admin order pages after billing adress:
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ) {
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Bezorg moment').':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta('Bezorg moment') . '</p>'; 
}

// Display the custom field value on email notifications:
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 4 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Bezorg moment').':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta('Bezorg moment') . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you want to **target "New Order" email notification only** use this instead:

```
// Display the custom field value on "New Order" notification:
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 4 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( 'new_order' === $email->id )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('delivery_date').':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta('Bezorg moment') . '</p>';
}
```

[image]